How to enable Pen Pressure in Clip Studio Paint installed via Bottles? (Linux Mint)
I have Clip Studio Paint version 2.2.0 installed. It sees my graphics tablet as a mouse.
My OS:
Linux Mint 22 Wilma / Cinnamon

Dependencies that I downloaded:
vcrun 2019 and 2015
fonts
d3dcompiller_47

Windows Version:
Windows 8.1

Runner:
soda-9.0.1
In the CSP itself, I checked the checkbox in the settings - Preferences - Tablet - Using tablet service: Wintab (I tried with this setting and without it)
(!) I also realized that perhaps the problem is that my CSP cannot reconnect to the tablet after I press any button with my mouse.
I disconnected the mouse from USB completely, then my CSP began to work adequately and began to see my tablet.
I also tried to configure the mouse disabling in bottle via the registry, set different variables and disabled/enabled dlls, but nothing worked.
I think I need to disable mouse visibility in bottle, maybe this will solve the problem. But I don't know how
